# How to get the balance of a wallet given a private view key, via RPC?

Tags: rpc, viewkey, address, privatekey, account

I'm aware of the `get_balance` function - https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_balance

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:18082/json_rpc -d 
'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_balance",
"params":{"account_index":0,"address_indices":[0,1]}}'
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'

===>
{.............}
```

However, it doesn't show how, at what point use the private view key, nor any keys at all.

How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `monero-wallet-rpc` program operates on a *wallet*, not just key(s). Create<sup>1</sup> yourself a view-only wallet and open that with the `monero-wallet-rpc` (either using the `--wallet-file=<file>` option or `open_wallet` RPC method).

Additionally, you need to understand that to get the *balance*, a view-only wallet is not sufficient alone, as you need to also track the spent status of outputs to know the wallet balance. See [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/7224/7493) for import/export of outputs and key-images, which you'll also need to perform.

<sup>1</sup>There are multiple ways to create your view-only wallet, one example is via `monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-view-key arg`.

Comment: But I haven't asked about `monero-wallet-rpc`. I've asked about RPC, and making requests to an RPC node

Comment: `monero-wallet-rpc` **is** the thing RPC you'd use. There are two different RPC interfaces with Monero: wallet and daemon. As you're asking about *wallet* functionality (balance), you use the *wallet* RPC.

Comment: "But I haven't asked about monero-wallet-rpc" <- You have though. You used a link to the `monero-wallet-rpc` documentation in your question.

Comment: Even if I asked about, now I'm saying: I'm not asking about wallet RPC. I'm asking about RPC on a remote node.

Comment: "remote node"s have no wallet level functionality. Your question specifically asks about the `get_balance` *wallet* RPC method. There is no daemon (remote or local) RPC method to get a wallets balance.

Comment: I'm asking about `get_balance`. Whether it require or involve wallet or not -- I have no idea. What I do know is that I want to get a **balance** of a certain **address**. And preferably without having to get a wallet and `wallet-cli` into this in any way. That is, via remote RPC node. What will this be?

Comment: "I'm asking about get_balance."<- yes, I know, which as I've answered and commented, is a monero-wallet-rpc method. And monero-wallet-rpc operates on a *wallet*. There is no RPC method (wallet or domain) that has a method to get a balance with your private view key alone.